# Headers & exit() causing an unresponsive form submit

Tags: php, html

**Problem** After downloading a CSV once, the form does not send a request on submission.

**Purpose**: To download a CSV file of information after choosing a few criteria for the download.

**PHP Scripts**:

`export.php` displays a HTML Form allowing the user to select certain criteria (which basically sets a couple of variables and then submitting those criteria in order to download the CSV file.

`exportEntrants.php` uses those variables set by the form to retrieve the appropriate data from the database, create the CSV data and then provide it as a download to the user.

So in `export.php` we have the following snippet:

```
require_once 'exportEntrants.php';
if(/*the form is submitted*/){
    export($criteria);
}
else{
    // Display the HTML Form
}
```

Which successfully calls the exportEntrants.php script when the form is submitted the first time.

Then in `exportEntrants.php` the data is created correctly and downloaded using:

```
function download($content,$title) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.'.csv";');
        echo $content;
        exit();
    }
```

After which, the download works fine, and the CSV is correct. However on-screen the form is still visible to the user, so clicking the Submit button once more should trigger the `if` statement described above and allow me to download the file again with the same or different criteria as I see fit.

This doesn't happen though, nothing happens. The form is still displayed on screen, nothing has changed on screen at all, but submitting the form does not reload the page or cause any action.

Can anyone see what could be causing this problem? I will provide any additional information as needed.

Thank you.

**EDIT** in response to Comment from Hakre below.

- Disabling Javascript made no difference.
- This issue has been tested in Firefox 7.0.1 and Chrome 14. I have not yet tried IE or Safari.
- The HTML of the form is as follows (I haven't included the criteria parts of the form as they work fine and the form is generated by a rather complicated function so it's not a small piece of HTML (lots of divs and spans):

  `<form action="/admin/export/export.php" method="post" name="exportForm" onsubmit="return formSubmit()"><input type="submit" name="submit_butt" value="EXPORT" class="button"></form>`

Comment: Try using [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or another HTTP analyzer to see if your request is actually sent.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I'll try that now. Thanks

EDIT:
The request is not being sent. I'm afraid having this new piece of knowledge doesn't help me much, but maybe someone else?

Comment: What happens if you disable javascript? Which browser are you using? What is the HTML of the form?

Comment: @hakre I'll edit the original post to include that information now.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using a non-standard header? Content-Disposition is not part of the HTTP standard. Please add a specific reference to an authoritative source how that header should work with the browser in question.

Comment: Content-Disposition is what is suggested by php.net [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Can you add a `Content-length` header as `strlen($content);`? Try removing quotes from around the filename if possible? Ensure the `$title` is valid (does not contain line breaks etc)?

Comment: @hakre Content-Disposition is an RFC-compliant HTTP/1.1 header http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1 and works for me in MSIE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @mjec The $title is valid, and the file can successfully download once, it's just if I try to download (even the same file) again without first refreshing the form manually that it does not work.

Comment: @mjec: Look at the right place, e.g. [RFC2616 HTTP 1/1 **15.5 Content-Disposition Issues** "Content-Disposition is not part of the HTTP standard, ..."](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.5) - only because it works (for you, obviously not for the OP), must not mean it's standardized in the protocol.

Comment: It's commonly used, but if you run into problems, it's always helpful to first look what can be the case. E.g. to check first if specs are followed.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752733/headers-exit-causing-an-unresponsive-form-submit/7753359#7753359), Headers & exit()  are causing nothing.

Comment: @hakre While Gnudiff has the correct answer below, your comment about turning Javascript off should have set me on the right path to solving this, so thank you for your response in particular. I did attempt turning JS off (and thought that I had done so) with no change in the problem, however it turned out that JS had NOT turned off and it was a JS issue which was causing this error.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom Houdmont: That actually was why I was asking you to turn it off  ;) Anyway, you finally found the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the request is not being sent, when you press button repeatedly, seems to indicate an issue in client side. Check the  formSubmit() function or page source of the client-side and see if maybe the attachment download somehow messed up Javascript.

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer. The formSubmit() was keeping track of the number of times it had been submitted and was preventing further submissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe in your question is not related to the code you've posted.

I'm unable to reproduce your problem:

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
        $title = 'test';
        $content = 'Example file.';

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: plain/text");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.'.txt";');
        echo $content;
        exit();

}

?>
<form method="post" action=""><input type="submit" name="submit" value="download"></form>
```

[Test for yourself](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R0OfhA). Hope this helps to clarify where not your error is at least.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Houdmont as I understand your question:
The file download scripts generally based on header function.
Using header() function has a condition that you can only send header information and can not **echo** or can not send any kind of text(space too) before or after it. Otherwise it will show you the **warning: that header() information is already sent**

Based on your code i tried one example:
In your case form action and download script, both are on same page so when your form is post check that any kind (even a space) data is printed before header() starts i.e  or  tag, or space. or you should cover whole  ...  in PHP if else statement.

I have uploaded simple image download script. here is link. You can download and run.
http://code.google.com/p/mixexperiments/downloads/detail?name=imagedownload.rar&can=2&q=

if still you dont get it, make me more clear, I will try my best